# modulus is not working when using doubles in c++

Tags: c++

Im not being allowed to use mod. I think it's not working because I'm using doubles; is there a way around this?  --- the commented areas arnt working

```
void displayResults(double num1, char oper, double num2)
{
     switch(oper)
     {
     case '+' :
     cout << num1 << "+" << num2 << "=" << (num1+num2) << endl;
     break;

     case '-' :
     cout << num1 << "-" << num2 << "=" << (num1-num2) << endl;
     break;

     case '*' :
     cout << num1 << "*" << num2 << "=" << (num1*num2) << endl;
     break; 

     case '/' :
          if ( num1==0 || num2==0)
          cout <<"A number divided by 0 or divided into 0 is always 0"<< endl;
          else
          cout << num1 << "/" << num2 << "=" << (num1/num2) /*+ (num1%num2) */ << endl;
          break; 
    // case '%' :
    // cout << num1 << "%" << num2 << "=" << (num1%num2);
    //break;
     }

}
```

Comment: You're not allowed? *How* is it not working? Compiler errors? Run-time Exceptions? Output not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulus operator `%` is an integral function.

You need to use `fmod` for floating-point.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`std::fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod). It has an overload for doubles:

```
#include <cmath>

std::fmod(num1, num2);
```

Comment: I don't really get it. Mathematically, for example, what's the remainder of 2.6/1.5?

Comment: @khajvah I may be Batman, but I'm no mathematician. :-)

Comment: @khajvah: If we want the remainder of a/b, where b is positive, write a = q * b + r. q has to be an integer, and we need 0 <= r < b. r is the remainder. I think of b is negative, then in math we use a positive r, but in programming a negative r is often used.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde According to `cppreference.com`, absolute value of `a-q*b` has to be smaller than absolute value of `b`, so when `b` is negative, we pick negative `q`. As a result, remainder is the same in both cases.

Comment: @khajvah: Ah yes, fmod gives the same sign as `a`. But this differs from it mathematical usage, so it's quite confusing sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

`%` is only allowed for integral types or unscoped enums, you can use [std::fmod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmodstd) for *double*:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double num1 = 5.5;
    double num2 = 3.0;
    double z = std::fmod(num1,num2);

    std::cout << z << std::endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could overload the '%' operator to perform the modulus operation on any type you like. There is no build-in support in the language for doubles, however.

Comment: What you mean by "build-in". Isn't `std` "build-in"? There seems to be a function in std for doubles

Comment: @khajvah there is a function, but not build in support for the *operator %* for doubles.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can rather replace your doubles with 'long int' , that will help you overcome  the error and this will also work with all integer based operations.

i made this change in one of my codes and got it right, with a warning though. But it did work just fine, so try that, it should work pretty well.